# music bot stops after playing music for 30-50 secs

Tags: ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

```
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")
const player = require("../../client/player")
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    cooldown: 5,
    aliases: ['p'],
    description: "Plays a song",
    usage: "?p <song/vid-URL>",
    category: "Music",

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        const songTitle = args.join(" ")
        const queue = await player.createQueue(message.guild);
        const nosongEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#3d35cc')
            .setDescription(`‼️ - Please provide a song URL or song name!`)

        if (!songTitle) return message.reply({ embeds: [nosongEmbed] })
        

        const novcEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#3d35cc')
            .setDescription(`‼️ - You have to be in a Voice Channel to use this command!`)

        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply({ embeds: [novcEmbed] })
        if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(message.member.voice.channel)

        let url = songTitle
            
            // Search for the song using the discord-player
            const result = await player.search(url, {
                requestedBy: message.author,
                searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
            })

            // finish if no tracks were found
            if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                return message.reply("No results")

            // Add the track to the queue
            const song = result.tracks[0]
            await queue.addTrack(song)
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("AQUA")
                .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})** has been added to the Queue`)
                .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
                .setFooter({ text: `Duration: ${song.duration}`})
            message.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
            if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
            

            

        }
        
    }
```

i used the command then the song just stops playing after 30-50 seconds, it is supposed to play till the music finishes and then keep staying in the voice channel until a few mins of no music

i have reinstalled ffmpeg

using:
discord.js : 13.14.0
discord-player: 5.2.2

Comment: Was there any error when the bot left and did the bot die/shutdown after it left the voice call? Or does it randomly decide to leave the voice call after 40 seconds? I can also recommend using ffmpeg-static and make sure you have downloaded the opus library.

Comment: it just randomly stops then leaves without crashing,i have downloaded the opus library.Also i cant play any other music after it